# Update progress from BackgroudDownloader when app is closed

Tags: c#, uwp, background-process

I am using BackgroundDownloader in my UWP app like:

```
private async void StartDownload()
{
    var destinationFile = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.CreateFileAsync("temp.zip", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
    var backgroundDownloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
    var downloadOperation = backgroundDownloader.CreateDownload(fileUrl, destinationFile);

    SendUpdatableToastWithProgress();
    var progressCallback = new Progress<DownloadOperation>();
    progressCallback.ProgressChanged += ProgressCallback_ProgressChanged;
    var opProgress = await downloadOperation.StartAsync().AsTask(progressCallback);
}

private void ProgressCallback_ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadOperation e)
{
    if (e.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive > 0)
    {
        var br = e.Progress.BytesReceived;
        var percent = br * 1.0 / e.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive;
        UpdateToastProgress(percent);
    }
}
```

Is there any chance how can I get ProgressChanged fired even the UWP App is closed?

Comment: If you want to trigger the ProgressChanged event and send toast when the app is closed, you could try to use the BackgroundDownloader in the Background task. In this case, the ProgressChanged event can be triggered. For more details about how to use BackgroundDownloader in the Background task, you can refer to this [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/backgroundtransfer/).

Comment: Thanks @Faywang-MSFT for your reply. I've checked the official sample and found that there are 2 types of notifications: **FailureTileNotification** and **SuccessTileNotification**. However, there is no "ProgressTileNotification" which would allow me to report progress of the download when the app is suspended or closed. Is there other way to report progress than in BackgroudTask?

Comment: In the foreground, you can not report progress of the download when the app closes, it will also be destroyed, you can only receive the notification about download completion when the app closes. If you want to report progress, maybe you could try to use the BackgroundDownloader in the Background task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no reliable option on how to update `BackgroundDonwloader` progress in `Toast` notification through `Progress<DownloadOperation>`.

As per [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks#background-task-resource-constraints), `BackgroundTask` could be suspended or killed based on the actual system state. That could happen before the `BackgroundDownloader` finishes its job and your `Toast` notification will look like it got *frozen*.

The best approach here is to update your `Toast` progress bar in the app suspended or exited event with `AdaptiveProgressBarValue.Indeterminate` with appropriate texting (e.g. Finishing download in background, etc.). Based on comments from @Faywang - MSFT you can still get notifications about successful or failed download even the app is closed or suspended.

Another approach would be to use `extendedExecutionUnconstrained` to be able to run `BackgroundTask` indefinitely. In that case, you would be able to update `Toast` progress with 'live' data and even more, to trigger new download via `BackgroundDownloader`. The downside of this approach is that your app [cannot be listed in Microsoft Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-in-the-background-indefinetly).